# Is every eigenvector of AA an eigenvector of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a (finite-dimensional) vector space and $A \colon V \to V$ a linear map.

Is it true that, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A\circ A$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$?

I know the converse statement is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}. $$
Or
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

No, it is false: consider in a real vector space  $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\implies A\circ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ and not of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

A rotation by 90° as represented by a matrix e.g.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
has no real eigenvalue ($\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2+1$ is the characteristic polynomial) and so no eigenvectors. The rotation by 180°
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
has the whole space as a space of eigenvectors and zero vector
.

Comment: I love this answer. It's very intuitive, since $A\cdot v$ is orthogonal to $v$, yet $A^2 \cdot v$ is anti parallel.