# Conditions for two eigenvectors of $AA$ to be eigenvectors of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional real vector space with inner product $\langle\cdot{,}\cdot\rangle$, and suppose $A$ is a symmetric linear map $V\to V$. Then, by the spectral theorem, $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Clearly, if $A$ is symmetric, so is $AA$. Suppose further that the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1} \dotsc,\lambda_{d}$ of $AA$ are all distinct, so that every eigenspace is one-dimensional. In other words, $AA$ has an orthonormal basis $(e_{1},\dotsc,e_{d})$ of eigenvectors, and such basis is *unique* (up to permutation and reflection).

Now, since every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $AA$, we may conclude, by the uniqueness of $(e_{1},\dotsc,e_{d})$, that $e_{i}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for every $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$.

**Question:** Relaxing the hypothesis that the eigenvalues of $AA$ are all distinct, and assuming only that $\lambda_{j} \neq \lambda_{k}$, can we conclude that $e_{j}$ and $e_{k}$ are eigenvectors of $A$?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357243

Comment: Orthonormal bases for symmetric linear maps with distinct eigenvalues are unique up to permutation *and reflection*. If $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_d$ is an orthonormal basis, then so is $\pm e_1, \pm e_2, \ldots, \pm e_d$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the comment. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with distinct eigenvalues.
If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix which commutes with $B$ then $A$
preserves each eigenspace of $B$, so $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously
diagonalised. Indeed $A$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $B$, by say
Lagrange interpolation.

In this example, take $B=A^2$. Then $AB=BA$ and so each eigenvector
of $B$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

For your last question: consider
$$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&2}.$$
Then we can take $e_1,\ldots,e_3$ to be the standard basis, but
$e_1$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Does the assumption that $B$ has distinct eigenvalues and commutes with a (non-necessarily symmetric) $A$ really imply that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes, since the eigenvectors of $B$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Think of the case where $B$ is diagonalisable.